# Efficient way to split a vector of cigars using mclapply

Tags: r, mclapply

I have a very large vector of cigars:

```
my.vector = c("44M2D1I","32M465N3M", "3S4I3D45N65M")
```

That I'd like to transform to a vector of splitted cigars - the logic is as follows: whenever I find a number followed by an N, I have to split it, that is why I splited "32M465N3M" to "32M","465N","3M"; and "3S4I3D45N65M" to "3S4I3D", "45N", "65M"; and "44M2D1I" did not get split because it had no "N" in it.

```
my.vector.split = c("44M2D1I, "32M", "465N", "3M", "3S4I3D", "45N", "65M").
```

My vector is very large so ideally I'd like to use the parallel capabilities of the cluster.  I'd like to use mclapply with ncores.

Ideally, I'd like to define something like this:

```
 my.vector.split = unlist(mclapply(my.vector, my.splitting.function, mc.cores = ncores))
```

where the length of my.vector.split is length(my.vector) + (number of Ns)*2.

Note. The HPC cluster I am using does not have the latest bioconductor installed so I cannot use cigartoRleList, and other nice cigar operation tools.

Comment: @Gsee, sorry, yes that's the result.   I changed it to the correct version.

Comment: @Dualinity, it is a character vector representing alignment of reads to reference genomes - more details here: http://samtools.sourceforge.net/SAMv1.pdf in page 5, point 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be applicable. Details will vary depending how you set up your clusters but basically this will return a series of dataframe. If you wanted them as vectors then wrap `unlist` around them:

```
 lapply(gsub("([[:digit:]]+N)", ",\\1,", my.vector) , 
         function(x) unlist( read.table(text=x,sep=",",colClasses="character")) )
#------------
[[1]]
       V1 
"44M2D1I" 

[[2]]
    V1     V2     V3 
 "32M" "465N"   "3M" 

[[3]]
      V1       V2       V3 
"3S4I3D"    "45N"    "65M"
```

Comment: I think this will be very slow.  I was thinking along the lines of `strsplit(gsub("(\\d+N)", "_\\1_", my.vector), "_")`, but that many not be as conducive to `mclapply`.  Also, there must be a way to not need both `strsplit` and `gsub`

Comment: @Gsee, mmm, if you think this may not be efficient you may be right... We could use strsplit directly if strsplit does not get rid of the match character... https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2006-April/037120.html... but seems that option is not yet implemented...

Comment: I assumed you wanted the gsub result parsed. Alternatively you may want to use `gregexpr` or `regexec` to identify locations for `substr` extraction.